# Doing like roslaunch in C++ : Launch NodeHandle with specific type

Tags: c++, ros

I'm new to ROS and i'm looking for launching a 'video_stream_opencv' node programatically.

Link below :
http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv

the launch file is working well with the commands roslaunch

```
<!-- images will be published at /camera_name/image with the image transports plugins (e.g.: compressed) installed -->
<group ns="$(arg camera_name)">
    <node pkg="video_stream_opencv" type="video_stream" name="$(arg camera_name)_stream" output="screen"> 
        <remap from="camera" to="image_raw" />
        <param name="camera_name" type="string" value="$(arg camera_name)" />
        <param name="video_stream_provider" type="string" value="$(arg video_stream_provider)" />
        <param name="fps" type="int" value="$(arg fps)" />
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)" />
        <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="$(arg camera_info_url)" />
        <param name="flip_horizontal" type="bool" value="$(arg flip_horizontal)" />
        <param name="flip_vertical" type="bool" value="$(arg flip_vertical)" />
        <param name="width" type="int" value="$(arg width)" />
        <param name="height" type="int" value="$(arg height)" />
    </node>

    <node if="$(arg visualize)" name="$(arg camera_name)_image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view">
        <remap from="image" to="image_raw" />
    </node>
</group>
```

But now i'm trying to do the same with C++ code but i don't see how to set the 'type' attributes in my node...

```
printf("Started ROS thread\n");

//glutInit(&argc, argv);

ros::init(argc, argv, "camera_name);
ROS_INFO("camera_name started");


// MY params to set
std::string camera_name = "toto";
std::string video_stream_provider = "toto";
int  fps  = 30;
std::string  frame_id= "toto";
std::string  camera_info_url= "toto";
bool flip_horizontal= false;
bool flip_vertical= false;
int width = 30;
int height = 30;

ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::M_string remappings;
remappings.insert(std::make_pair("camera", "image_raw"));
ros::NodeHandle node_handle(nh, "camera_name",remappings);

node_handle.setParam("type",video_stream);
node_handle.setParam("camera_name",camera_name);
node_handle.setParam("video_stream_provider",video_stream_provider );
node_handle.setParam("fps",fps);
node_handle.setParam("frame_id",frame_id);
node_handle.setParam("camera_info_url", camera_info_url);
node_handle.setParam("flip_horizontal", flip_horizontal);
node_handle.setParam("flip_vertical",flip_vertical);
node_handle.setParam("width", width);
node_handle.setParam("height", height);
```

Comment: I personally don't understand exactly what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to start the node "image_view" from inside the main() function of the "camera_name" node? If so, that's not possible.

Comment: You could start a second node by the `std::system()` call. This is like starting it from the console.

Answer (score 2):

Reviving an old thread to help those in need.

I have created a class for this purpose that is based upon "rosspawn".

ros_launch_manager.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "ros/console.h"
#include "rospack/rospack.h"

class ROSLaunchManager 
{
    std::vector<pid_t> m_pids;

    std::atomic<bool> m_running;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    
public:
    ROSLaunchManager(ROSLaunchManager const &)
    {
    }

    ROSLaunchManager()
    {
        std::atomic_init(&m_running, true);

        m_thread = std::thread(&ROSLaunchManager::wait, this);
    }

    ~ROSLaunchManager() 
    {
        if (m_running.load()) {
            m_running.store(false);

            if (m_thread.joinable()) {
                m_thread.join();
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    pid_t start(Args... args) 
    {
        std::vector<std::string> args_vector = { args... };

        if (args_vector.size() > 0) {
            pid_t pid = ::fork();

            if (pid == 0) {
                ::setsid();
                
                ::signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
                
                ::fclose(stdout);
                ::fclose(stdin);
                ::fclose(stderr);

                ::execlp("roslaunch", "roslaunch", args..., nullptr);
            }
            else {
                std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> scoped_lock(m_mutex);

                std::string args_string = std::accumulate(std::next(std::begin(args_vector)), std::end(args_vector), args_vector[0], [](std::string lhs, std::string rhs) -> std::string { return lhs + " " + rhs; });

                ROS_INFO("Starting \"roslaunch %s\" with PID %d", args_string.c_str(), pid);

                m_pids.push_back(pid);
            }

            return pid;
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("ROSLaunchManager::start - No arguments provided");
        }
    }

    void stop(pid_t const &pid, int32_t const &signal) 
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> scoped_lock(m_mutex);

        auto pid_it = std::find(std::begin(m_pids), std::end(m_pids), pid);

        if (pid_it != m_pids.end()) {
            ::kill(pid, signal);

            ROS_INFO("Stopping process with PID %d and signal %d", pid, signal);
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("ROSLaunchManager::stop - PID " + std::to_string(pid) + " not found");
        }
    }

private:
    void wait()
    {
        while (m_running.load()) {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> scoped_lock(m_mutex);

            for (auto pid_it = std::begin(m_pids); pid_it != std::end(m_pids); ++pid_it) {
                pid_t const pid = *pid_it;

                int32_t status;

                if (::waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED | WNOHANG) == pid) {
                    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                        ROS_INFO("PID %d exited with status %d", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));

                        pid_it = m_pids.erase(pid_it);

                        if (pid_it == std::end(m_pids)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                        ROS_INFO("PID %d killed with signal %d", pid, WTERMSIG(status));

                        pid_it = m_pids.erase(pid_it);

                        if (pid_it == std::end(m_pids)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                        ROS_INFO("PID %d stopped with signal %d", pid, WSTOPSIG(status));
                    } 
                    else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
                        ROS_INFO("PID %d continued"   , pid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> scoped_lock(m_mutex);

        for (pid_t const &pid : m_pids) {
            ::kill(pid, SIGINT);

            int32_t status;

            ::waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
ROSLaunchManager ros_launch_manager;
pid_t rtabmap_pid;

// Start roslaunch program

try {
    rtabmap_pid = ros_launch_manager.start(
        "rtabmap_ros", "rtabmap.launch", 
        "rtabmap_args:=\"--delete_db_on_start\"", 
        "depth_topic:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw", 
        "rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw",
        "camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info",
        "approx_sync:=false");
}
catch (std::exception const &exception) {
    ROS_WARN("%s", exception.what());
}

// Stop roslaunch program

try {
    ros_launch_manager.stop(rtabmap_pid, SIGINT);
}
catch (std::exception const &exception) {
    ROS_WARN("%s", exception.what());
}
```

When ros_launch_manager is destroyed all of its processes are killed. The processes can be stopped/continued as well with SIGSTOP/SIGCONT.

Answer (score 0):

The only two ways i know of launching a rosnode is either from Terminal using rosrun or by Launch files.

https://answers.ros.org/question/198279/how-to-start-a-ros-node/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are asking about setting the type of a parameter for a rosnode.

In roscpp, include/ros/node_handle.h,
setParam() does have multiple variants, each designed to handle a particular type of parameter.

```
 void setParam(const std::string& key, const std::string& s) const;

 void setParam(const std::string& key, const char* s) const;

 void setParam(const std::string& key, double d) const;
```

and so on.

You have already done that in your code.